# Tropical geometry

Tags: reference-request, tropical-geometry

I studied algebraic geometry and looked for the development of some concepts and found tropical geometry is an important field. I need a simple reference to explain tropical geometry and its applications please.

Comment: The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry) isn't a bad place to start.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an introductory article:

https://www.ams.org/publications/journals/notices/201704/rnoti-p380.pdf

and an introductory book:

**Introduction to Tropical Geometry
by Diane Maclagan and Bernd Sturmfels**

And finally here is a book that gives a fairly current state of our knowledge in the field:

**Nonarchimedean and Tropical Geometry by Matthew Baker and Sam Payne**

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much that it is very useful